# Problem with selecting the RSS parser in python

Tags: python

My code is :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "example.com/feed/"

resp = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, features="xml")

items = soup.findAll('item')
for i in range(4):
    news_items = [str(i)]

for item in items:
    news_item = {}
    news_item['title'] = item.title.text
    news_item['description'] = item.description.text
    news_item['link'] = item.link.text
    news_items.append(news_item)

print(news_item['link'])
print(news_item['link'])
print(news_item['link'])
print(news_item['link'])
```

i want the outcome will be one `news_item['link']`. when i compile this code it only gives me the same `news_item['link']`, i want second third and ... for the outcome.
help me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put `print(news_item['link'])` within the `for` loop.

Your code should be something like this:

**Code**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "example.com/feed/"

resp = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, features="xml")

items = soup.findAll('item')
for i in range(4):
    news_items = [str(i)]

for item in items:
    news_item = {}
    news_item['title'] = item.title.text
    news_item['description'] = item.description.text
    news_item['link'] = item.link.text
    news_items.append(news_item)
    print(news_item['link'])
```

Comment: Thanks i do this and problem solved, But i have another problem and i want to print one item at a time and after that, it goes on another item
for example:
https://link1.com

Answer (score 1):

In your current you print last item in `items` executed in the `for` loop.

move your print **inside** the for loop to print every item you want like this:

```
for item in items:
    news_item = {}
    news_item['title'] = item.title.text
    news_item['description'] = item.description.text
    news_item['link'] = item.link.text
    news_items.append(news_item)
    print(news_item['link'])
```

Comment: Thanks i do this and problem solved, But i have another problem and i want to print one item at a time and after that, it goes on another item for example: link1.com and than, Link2.com

Comment: this what exactly this code is do for you. in every for loop iteration it prints `news_item['link']` of that item